# Github actions, self hosted runner Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: ssl, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am using self hosted runner behind a corporate proxy. I added our certificates but when doing :

```
  - name: Setup Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: 'adopt'
      java-package: jdk
      java-version: '11'
```

I am getting the error :

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Any hint?
Thank you

Comment: Can you verify your certificates on your runners? Do you know if your proxy intercepts requests?

Comment: The certificates must be added only at the system level ?

A curl to https://github.com gives me a 200.

Comment: Can you SSH into your runners? What if you curl the host where it's trying to download the jdk from?

Comment: Yes I can SSH.
The command :
`curl -L https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases/download/3.10.4-2034678717/python-3.10.4-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz -o python-source.tar.gz`

But with -L it works.

Comment: 1) in the question your talking about java, but this curl command is for python? 2) also try adding `-i -v` (show headers)

Comment: With Java, I am getting :

`Run actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
    distribution: adopt
    java-package: jdk
    java-version: 11
    architecture: x64
    check-latest: false
    server-id: github
    server-username: GITHUB_ACTOR
    server-password: GITHUB_TOKEN
    overwrite-settings: true
    job-status: success
  env:
    FORCE_COLOR: 2
Trying to resolve the latest version from remote
Error: unable to verify the first certificate`

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I am in the same boat

Comment: After whitelisted the urls, it still doesn't work.

Should the proxy setting be set somewhere else ? It is set at the "container level" as env variable : http_proxy and https_proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding env :

```
   env:
     - name: SSL_CERT_DIR
       value: "/etc/ssl/certs"
```

In runner deployment fixed the issue.